# How to loop through a line of a csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell

How to loop through a line of a csv file in powershell.

I want to process a csv file in powershell, but I don't know what the column headings in the CSV file will be when it is processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$header3 = @("Field_1","Field_2","Field_3","Field_4","Field_5")     

Import-Csv $fileName -Header $header3 -Delimiter "`t" | select -skip 3 | 
Foreach-Object {

    $record = $indexName 
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties){

        #doSomething $property.Name, $property.Value

            if($property.Name -like '*TextWrittenAsNumber*'){

            $record = $record + "," + '"' + $property.Value + '"' 
        }
        else{
            $record = $record + "," + $property.Value 
        }                           
  }               

    $array.add($record) | out-null  
    #write-host $record                         
 }
```